# jQuery: replace text inside link but not in tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I've got a html:

```
<div class="sth-key">
    <p>
        key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
        <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        and the final <strong>key</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

and I want to replace word 'key' that is not inside attributes, with 'pencil', so the output would look like this:

```
<div class="sth-key">
    <p>
        pencil here <span class="keyify">and here a pencil</span>
        <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a pencil</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        and the final <strong>pencil</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

I've tried to do this with

```
$('.sth-key p').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('key','pencil'));
});
```

or with text()... but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.contents()` method in order to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree.

Also, you have to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method in order to `replace` your text.

I used [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function in order to go through all childrens of the `p` element.

The `nodeType` property returns the node type, as a number, of the specified node.

**Here are `main` node types**:

> If the node is an `element` node, the nodeType property will return 1.
>
> If the node is an `attribute` node, the nodeType property will return 2.
>
> If the node is a `text` node, the nodeType property will return 3.

```js
$('.sth-key p').each(function(){
 $(this).contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) 
                this.nodeValue=$(this).text().replace("key", "pencil")
            if(this.nodeType===1)
                $(this).html( $(this).html().replace("key", "pencil") )
        });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sth-key">
    <p>
        key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
        <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        and the final <strong>key</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the text method and pass a function to replace all 'key' with 'pencil'.

```
​$(".sth-key").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("key", "pencil"); 
});​​​​​
```

I didn't test this yet but I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `"key"` with `/key/g`, which is a regular expression that will search globally. If you use replace like you did, it will stop at the first occasion.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sth-key p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/key/g, 'pencil'));
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="sth-key">
  <p>
    key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
    <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    and the final <strong>key</strong>
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's more information: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: ERROR: it will change your attributes as well. I suggest using the `.contents()` method that has been used in other answers

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.sth-key p').each(function(i,elem){
    let html = $(elem).html().replace(/key/g,'pencil');
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sth-key">
<p>
    key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
    <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
</p>
<p>
    and the final <strong>key</strong>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to help, my friend

Comment: But by cheating

Comment: and how that happend?!

Comment: Check your html code and the asked one. You will come to know

Comment: all answers here took OP code for snippet ?! I wanted to run my answer and check how it works with OP html? I don't of what you trying to accuse me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133925/discussion-between-prashant-pokhriyal-and-kejt).

Answer (score 0):

According to [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

You can :

```js
$('.sth-key p').contents().each(function(idx, ele) {
  // get only TEXT_NODE or ELEMENT_NODE 
  if (ele.nodeType === 3 || ele.nodeType === 1) {
    ele.textContent = ele.textContent.replace('key','pencil');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="sth-key">
    <p>
        key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
        <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        and the final <strong>key</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code iterates over all text nodes and replaces `key` word with `pencil`

```js
$('.sth-key p').each(keyToPencil);

function keyToPencil() {
  var iter = document.createNodeIterator(this, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
  while (node = iter.nextNode()) {
    node.data = node.data.replace(/key/g, 'pencil');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sth-key">
  <p>
    key here <span class="keyify">and here a key</span>
    <a href="/key-anything" title="dont change that key">and a key</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    and the final <strong>key</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Improved - let me know.

Answer (score -1):

This code only replace when text only in p.
if text in span inside of p this does not replace

```
$(".sth-key p").text(function (_, ctx) {
    return ctx.replace("key", "pencil");
});
```

Comment: but it should replace "key" with "pencil" inside of span too, just not in the attribute-values